# How to spot a change in a date sequence?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to know if there's a way to find the value where a sequence of dates switches.

For example, I have an array like this:

["2005-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31","2008-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31"]

The dates all move from 2005 to 2007 before switching to 2006 and then starting again. I need to start writing to a new line when this happens but just can't figure out a way to monitor it and tell my script to move to a new line at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by sequence? Do you only care about the year, or do you also want it to flag when the month/day change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method can be written, which returns an array of indexes where the sequence breaks (regresses to an older year and breaks the ascending order):

```
def sequence_break_points(arr)
  change_points = []
  arr.each_with_index do |e, idx|
    next if idx == 0
    change_points << idx if (e < arr[idx-1])
  end
  change_points
end
```

In this case you can use the method as follows:

```
arr = ["2005-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31","2008-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31"]
years_arr = arr.map { |date| date.split("-").first.to_i }

sequence_break_points(years_arr)
=> [4]
# This is the point in the array where the sequence broke.
# The results of this method can be used to tell the script
# when to start a new line
```

I'm sure there's better ways of doing this, but I believe this will get the job done.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, this returns 1 and 4. I believe you have a fencepost / one-off error in your loop - for the first array element, arr[idx-1] = arr[-1]; this wraps around and accesses the last array element.

Comment: Ahh duh. For some reason i thought doing the shift on the array beforehand would remedy that, but of course it was still taking the -1 of the new array. Thanks for the feedabck. Fixing.